# Is it possible to stop the --watch option always compiling everything 1st

Tags: typescript

I'd like the `tsc --watch` option to not compile everything when run. I guess it would have to only compile files only if the time stamps of the .js files are older than the .ts source files (much like good old make does).

It's not a big issue, but I'm using TS with a program that monitors `.js` files and reloads them when the they change (actually the Azure Functions CLI host). I run this program in parallel with `tsc --watch` and with the current behaviour it reloads every file as each is compiles.

I guess I could put in a delay before the functions host funs but that's hacky.

thanks

Comment: Thanks. It certainly appears so which is a shame as don't want to jump to webpack. Just npm scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to stop the --watch option always compiling everything 1st

Not with just `typescript` built in.

## More

You can write code to to the timestamp caching and checks yourself.